# Use leaflet-arc in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

How do I use the [leaflet-arc plugin](https://github.com/mad-gooze/Leaflet.Arc) in Angular? What I've tried so far:

1. `npm install --save leaflet-arc`
2. Add `"scripts": ["node_modules/leaflet-arc/src/leaflet-arc.js"]` to
   `angular.json`.
3. Add `import '../../../node_modules/leaflet-arc/src/leaflet-arc.js';`
   to `my-component.component.ts`.

However when I do the following inside `my-component.component.ts`, it still gives me an error that `Property 'Arc' does not exist on type 'typeof Polyline'.`:

`L.Polyline.Arc(...)`

When I do `ng serve` this actually works, but it still gives the error when compiling.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work you need to follow these steps:

1. `npm i leaflet --save`
2. `npm install --save leaflet-arc`

Go to angular.json an add the two libraries as follows:

```
 "styles": [
      "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
      "src/styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
      "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js",
      "node_modules/leaflet-arc/src/leaflet-arc.js"
  ]
```

In app.component.ts you need to import the two libraries as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-arc'; // import leaflet-arc here

declare let L;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        const map = L.map('map').setView([60, 100], 3);
        // create an arc here
        L.Polyline.Arc([59.56667, 150.80000], [67.50000, 64.03333], {
            color: 'red',
            vertices: 200
        }).addTo(map);

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);
    }
}
```

template:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

style:

```
#map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/l7o5zk0m7)

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Looks like the issue was fixed by that `declare let L`. Nice fix!

Comment: Thanks. Yes,indeed, make sure to import both leaflet & leaflet-arc in your template and then use `declare let L`.

Comment: Actually noticing that I'm getting an error giving an unexpected identifier from the line `import arc from 'arc';`. It runs correctly, but would like to fix that error

Comment: I guess not with the code I provided cause I did not use that line. In my local copy where I tested it I was not getting any errors